# Batch coding - Line is ignored?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am coding a very simple batch script.

What I want is to change a filename, move it to another folder, upload it through a PHP script and delete the file once uploaded.

Here is my script:

```
ren K:\videos\Videos\8e9ced3f63.480.mp4 -48984023_168954163.mp4
move K:\videos\Videos\-48984023_168954163.mp4 K:\videos\Videos\uploading\-48984023_168954163.mp4 
php vm_upload.php K:\videos\Videos\uploading\-48984023_168954163.mp4 
del K:\videos\Videos\uploading\-48984023_168954163.mp4
```

If I enter those command one by one in cmd.exe, it works well, but when I run a .bat file containing the exact same code, it does everything super fast, it changes the filename, moves it, and then deletes it without uploading it.

This is the first time I'm coding in batch, I might be doing something wrong, please let me know.

Comment: PHP-CLI will execute the PHP script but will not halt the execution of the batch script. I'd recommend that you add a `pause` at the end of the script so you can see if PHP returned any kind of error. Also, remember that when you use PHP-CLI you no longer use the webserver path, you are using the path you are currently running the script from.

Comment: @CristianHG You saved me hours CristianHG, thank you very much, it was about the path. I feel so dumb :)

Answer (score -2):

I would add a `ping localhost -n 2 >nul` after the `move` command and see if that helps?

It seems like the PHP command does not wait for a response before moving on, it just sends it to the php interface. the command above will wait a second then move on.

Edit: I now see that it was a problem with the URL, interesting that it did not show an error pop-up as my php would. When in doubt add pauses as @CristianHG did.